# "Groom" in Marriage?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

Groom for me as I know it means a man who tends to the horses, or and in the verb form, it is to take care of one's appearance. Then, why is it used to refer to the man of the marriage? Is there any etymological reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> groom (n.1) 
>   c.1200, grome "male child, boy;" c.1300 as "youth, young man." No known cognates in other Germanic languages. Perhaps from O.E. *groma, related to growan "grow;" or from O.Fr. grommet "servant" (cf. M.E. gromet "ship's boy," early 13c.). Meaning "male servant who attends to horses" is from 1660s.
>
> groom (n.2) 
>   husband-to-be at a wedding, c.1600, short for bridegroom, in which the second element is O.E. guma "man."
>
> groom (v.) 
>   1809, from groom (n.1) in its secondary sense of "male servant who attends to horses;" the transferred sense of "to tidy (oneself) up" is from 1843; figurative sense of "to prepare a candidate" is from 1887, originally in U.S. politics. Related: Groomed; grooming.

That's what [EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=groom) gives for the *groom*. It seems these are two different words with same spelling and pronunciation.

Answer (score 12):

As [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=groom) reports, ***groom*** in the meaning of “husband-to-be at a wedding” is circa 1600. It is a shortening of ***bridegroom***. *Bridegroom* itself is earlier, from the Old English *brydguma* (suitor), from *bryd* (bride) + *guma* (man). The Old English *brydguma* ending was altered in the 16th century to align with *groom* (in the sense of “boy”, “lad”).

It's nice to note that it's reportedly the only word in which the [Old English *guma*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=human) (man) is still present. This *guma*, which comes from Proto Germanic *guman*, was displaced by its cognate *human*, from Middle French *humain*, from Latin *humanus*.

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: @Philoto: 32 seconds, *with formatting* :)